# When storing array in h5py dataset the dimensions is changed?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, h5py

I have a 2d list that contains a 3d array and a label, I try to save data in the h5py file with two datasets (data and label) one for 3d array and another one for the label, but when displaying the content of 'data' dataset which stores the 3d array the result of showing is 4d array. my code for creating h4py file:

```
Data_set = get3Dmatrix(ID_list) # 2d list
data = []
label = []
for i in range(len(Data_set)):
    data.append(Data_set[i][0])
    label.append(Data_set[i][1])

label = [int(i) for i in labels]#convert label to int

with h5py.File(output_path+'dataset.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('data', data=data, compression='lzf')
    hf.create_dataset('label', data=label, compression='lzf')
print("Creating h5py file is completed")
print("%s time takes in seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my code for displaying the content of 3d array dataset:

```
hf = h5py.File(output_path+'dataset.h5', 'r')
dt = hf.get('data')
lbl = hf.get('label')
print(dt[0:1])
```

the content of my 2d list is like the image below:
[image]

The array that I get when showing it is like the image below:
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not comparing like objects. The remark `the content of my 2d list is like the image below` implies you expect your HDF5 file to reflect your list or arrays. But in your code you convert your list of arrays into a single NumPy array before assigning to an HDF5 dataset. This is the relevant line:

```
data = np.array(data)
```

Let's see a *minimal* example of what's happening with some sample data:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])

arr2 = np.array([[10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15],
                 [16, 17, 18]])
```

Now let's create a list of arrays from these individual arrays. As you can see, you have a two 2d arrays in a list:

```
L = [arr1, arr2]

print(L)

[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]),
 array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])]
```

What happens when we convert to a NumPy array? NumPy collapses the list structure and produces a single NumPy array of homogeneous type, which can now be held in a contiguous memory block. There are no list pointers involved. This is exactly what you should expect.

```
A = np.array(L)

print(A)

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```

Your input arrays have 2 dimensions, so it seems entirely reasonable that NumPy converts a *list* of such arrays to a single array with 3 dimensions. If you require a 2d array, you'll have to instruct NumPy *how* to combine your multiple arrays. For example, using `numpy.vstack`:

```
B = np.vstack(L)

print(B)

array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: you the lines that I convert the (data and label) list into numpy array before creating the h5py file? if you meant that, I did the work without converting the two lists to numpy array and I get the same result?

Comment: sorry for that, by 'But in your code you convert your list of arrays into a single NumPy array before assigning to an HDF5 dataset' you mean these two lines of my code data = np.array(data)
label = np.array(label)

Comment: @honar.cs, Yes, exactly. You *should* expect a difference. You aren't passing a list of arrays, you are passing an array constructed from a list of arrays, which will always add a dimension. See example at the end of my answer for what you *may* be looking for.

Comment: ok, if I convert my data list to np.vstack, it solves my problem?

Comment: @honar.cs, Possibly. Depends what you want. Try it, see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I think the problem is not there, because I try the code without converting the (data and label) lists to numpy array and I get same result

Comment: @honar.cs, Sure. I've demonstrated there's a difference. You should update your question with precisely what you want.

Comment: thank you for your attempt to answer my question, the code is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

I may be repeating @jpp's answer, but I need work write out this detail to understand what's going on.

If I read the problem correctly, `Data_set` is a list of pairs (lists), each consisting of a 3d array and a single character string.

This loop splits it into 2 lists:

```
data = []
label = []
for i in range(len(Data_set)):
    data.append(Data_set[i][0])
    label.append(Data_set[i][1])
```

alternatively it could be written as

```
data = [a[0] for a in Data_set]
label = [a[1] for a in Data_set]
```

or even

```
data, label = list(zip(*Data_set))
```

When you save `data`:

```
hf.create_dataset('data', data=data, compression='lzf')
```

`h5py` converts it to an array (it can only save `np.array` sources).

Look at `np.array(data).shape`.  It will be 4d.  That looks like a logical data structure for a collection of 3d arrays (identical sized).

That could be turned back into a list of 3d arrays, e.g. `list(dt)`.

You could do `data = np.concatenate(data, axis=0)` before the same.  That would produce a 3d array, but then you loose all boundaries between the original 3d arrays.